# Android: How to brighten up the image of a button when clicked?

Tags: android, xml

I know when a button(without background) is clicked, it changes its color and then flow goes to its onClickListner. But when i set an Image to the Button, it is not the same. I want may Image in Button to brighten up a little so that it will look nice.

I know it has something to do with styling but dont know what style to use,
below is my xml code for the button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/supplier"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/two_player"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/two_player"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:background="@drawable/supplier" />
```

Comment: You have to customize the button using `Selector` to achieve that

Comment: Please accept my ans if its work for you thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one buttonselector in drawable folder then set it button background

**btnselector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_clicked" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Now set this to button background as like

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/supplier"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/two_player"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/two_player"
android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/btnselector" />
```

i think you got it ...

Comment: you mean i should have two drawables of the same button?? is not possible to just brighten up the same image when selected

Comment: hey @SujayKumar those doesn't necessarily have to be a drawable. You can use just a color code or a `<shape>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Selector to achieve that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!--  Active tab -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />

  <!--  Inactive tab -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected" />

  <!--  Pressed tab -->
  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_pressed" />

  <!--  Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
  <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Supposing the above file is called bg_selector, you set it as the background of the object you want to brighten, and in your case the 'Pressed tab' is what you're looking for. In my 'tab_bg_pressed' you would define another drawable where you would set the background as a brighten effect or whatever you want.